# Pass a method with N params as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, delegates, action

I have several methods all returning void with different signature (parameters) and different names. I need to pass those methods as a parameter in a generic method that will invoke it latter. Also that need to be as transparent as possible.

Following what I got so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action<string,int> TestHandler = Test;
        InvokeMyMethod(TestHandler);

        Action<string, int,object > TestHandlerN = TestN;
        InvokeMyMethod(TestHandlerN);
    }        
public void InvokeMyMethod(Delegate Method)
    {
          object[] args = new object[X];            
          Method.DynamicInvoke();
    }

    public void Test(string t1, int t2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t1 + t2);
    }

    public void TestN(string t1, int t2, object t3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t1 + t2);
    }
```

That is what I need:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeMyMethod(Test);
        InvokeMyMethod(TestN);
    }

    public void InvokeMyMethod(XXX_Type Method)
    {
         object[] args = new object[X];
         Method.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }

    public void Test(string t1, int t2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t1 + t2);
    }

    public void TestN(string t1, int t2, object t3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t1 + t2);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it easiest to do this with delegates? Each different signature requires a struct into which you put that parameters. The struct exposes a single method, `Execute` which then calls the real method passing the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but when calling `TestN("Test", 1)`, what should the value of `t3` be?  `null`?  Should the call fail?

Comment: Is your goal simply to get rid of the explicit delegate type declarations?

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) how you are handling the different signatures. It seems that TestN would fail since t3 is not optional. At what point do you know what the values for the parameters are going to be?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but here is how I solve a similar problem:

```
public static partial class Lambda
{
    public static Action Pin<T0>
        (
            this Action<T0> action,
            T0 arg0
        )
    {
        return () => action(arg0);
    }

    public static Func<TResult> Pin<T0, TResult>
        (
            this Func<T0, TResult> func,
            T0 arg0
        )
    {
        return () => func(arg0);
    }

    public static Action Pin<T0, T1>
        (
            this Action<T0, T1> action,
            T0 arg0,
            T1 arg1
        )
    {
        return () => action(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public static Func<TResult> Pin<T0, T1, TResult>
        (
            this Func<T0, T1, TResult> func,
            T0 arg0,
            T1 arg1
        )
    {
        return () => func(arg0, arg1);
    }

    // More signatures omitted for brevity...
    // I would love it if C# supported variadic template parameters :-)
}
```

The idea is that if you have an `Action` which requires arguments, you can say:

```
Action<int, string> foo;
Action a = foo.Pin(5, "bleh");
```

Have the [code generator](http://pastebin.com/bgtF241w).

Likewise, you might want to have a way to curry to some other delegate type (like `Action<string, int>`).  The difference between my method and yours is that mine is not late-bound, but you do not appear to be using late-binding anyway, so early-binding gives you some compile-time type safety.

I'm not sure you can do what I think you are asking.  You call `method.DynamicInvoke` with some `object[]`, but how did you get values for those parameters?

---

And to answer the question before anybody asks it, I created the `Lambda.Pin` functions because I was tired of making this mistake:

```
Action<int> foo;
foreach (int i in someList)
    AddAction(() => foo(i));
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I've been doing. It is a royal pain in the ass but I don't see any other way.

Comment: I added a link to my simple code generator.  Feel free to use it and change it any way you want to, since it is probably shoddily written anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void InvokeMyMethod(Delegate method) {
    Method.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {"Test", 1});
}
```

But you need to invoke it like

```
InvokeMyMethod((Action<string, int>)Test);
```

Comment: Let suppose that my method has 6 parameters I will have to create a new delegate just for that method, thats why I need to be transparent

Comment: If you don't accept the cast when converting the method group to a delegate, you're out of luck. Sorry.